# 403 Forbidden even after all browser headers were copied

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

So I've been toying with this for about an hour. I thought I've had a lot of practice with mechanize, but I guess not. I've been trying to load a webpage, and I thought after copying all browser headers, I'd be good but I've copied it all (user-agent, and about 5 others). Take a look at what I've set so far:

```
Br = mechanize.Browser()
Br.addHeaders = [("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0)  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"),("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5"),("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"),("Connection","keep-alive"),("Host","fiverr"),("Cache-Control","max-age=0")]
Br.set_handle_robots(False)
Br.set_handle_equiv(False)
```

Still, when I make the request, I just get httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I think the answer is something to do with cookies, but when I remove all cookies in Firefox, then load the page, it still loads fine. So there is not initial cookie required. I believe mechanize accepts cookies on default, so I haven't coded anything involving cookies.

Does anyone have any ideas what I should try next?